# Python - Searching for the Richest customer in a text file

Tags: python, file, file-io, python-3.x

I am having some issues with some code I am writing. I am attempting to find the customer in a file with the largest bank balance. An example of the text file is:

12345,John,Doe,300.00,1998-01-30

23456,Jane,Doe,1200.50,1998-02-20

In this case Jane Doe has the largest balance and I want to print her entire file/line. How can I go about this? Here's what I have so far:

```
def get_best_customer(customer_file):

    customer_file.seek(0)
    richest = 0
    customer_info = []

    for line in customer_file:
        line = customer_file.readline().strip()
        balance = line.split(',')
        if balance > richest:
            customer_info.append(balance)

    return customer_info
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3):

You can define a "key" function that takes a line and returns the money field. Then `max` can be used directly

```
def get_best_customer(customer_file):

    customer_file.seek(0)

    def get_money(line):
        return float(line.split(',')[3])

    print(max(customer_file, key=get_money))
```

Answer (score 1):

`line.split(',')` returns a list strings --> `['23456', 'Jane', 'Doe', '1200.50', '1998-02-20']`.  You then need to convert the fields you are interested in:

```
line = customer_file.readline().strip()
data = line.split(',')
balance = float(data[3])
```

and that should get you going.  You still need to set `richest`, do your comparisons, and probably just set `customer_info` to `data`, not append to it.

Answer (score 0):

Gnibbler's answer can be written this way, I think:

```
def get_best_customer(customer_file):

    with open(customer_file, "r") as f:
        return max(f, key=(lambda l: float(l.strip().split(",")[3])))
```

Comment: Yes, but it's harder to debug and impossible to unittest. If there _is_ some corner cases to handle this lambda will quickly become messy.